# CGImageRef not init/alloc correctly

Tags: objective-c, nsimage, cgimageref

I am currently having problems with `CGImageRef`.

Whenever I create a `CGImageRef` and look at it in debugger view, in Xcode, it is `nil`.

Here's the code:

```
-(void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
    if (self.shoulddrag) {
        NSPoint event_location = [theEvent locationInWindow];//direct from the docs
        NSPoint local_point = [self convertPoint:event_location fromView:nil];//direct from the docs

        CGImageRef theImage = (__bridge CGImageRef)(self.image);
        CGImageRef theClippedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(theImage, CGRectMake(local_point.x,local_point.y,1,1));

        NSImage * image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:theClippedImage     size:NSZeroSize];

        self.pixleView.image = image;
        CGImageRelease(theClippedImage);
    }
}
```

Everything else seems to be working though. I can't understand. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: `self.pixelView` is an `NSImageView` instance that has not been overridden in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Alright, I figured it out.

What I was using to create the `CGImageRef` was:

```
    CGImageRef theImage = (__bridge CGImageRef)(self.image);
```

Apparently what I should have used is:

```
    CGImageSourceRef theImage = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)[self.image TIFFRepresentation], NULL);
```

I guess my problem was that for some reason I thought `NSImage` and `CGImageRef` had toll free bridging.

 Apparently, I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely `local_point` is not inside of the image. You've converted the point from the window to the view coordinates, but that may not be equivalent to the image coordinates. Test this to see if the lower-left corner of your image results in `local_point` being `(0,0)`.

It's not clear how your view is laid out, but I suspect that what you want to do is subtract the origin of whatever region (possibly a subview) the user is interacting with relative to `self`.

Comment: Yes, I was aware that I had a problem with `local_point`. However, I have already tried using `(0,0,1,1)` instead of `(local_point.x, local_point.y, 1, 1)`. And it still didn't work